# Will i feel any performance improvement in page load if i switch sIFR to @font-face?

Tags: css, xhtml, sifr, font-face

Will i feel any performance improvement in page load if i switch sIFR to @font-face?

I made a site on client request with a sIFR because client wanted to use his logo's font in Home Page heading and subheadings etc.

Now client feel site is slow to load because on homepage itself there are 20 instances of sIFR text.

Now if I suggest to client to change sIFR to @font-face then will it make a noticeable difference in page speed?

Client has his own custom font which is not available in **Google font library** and he need compatibility with IE 6 to 8 also.

Answer (score 0):

> Now if I suggest to client to change sIFR to @font-face then will it make a noticeable difference in page speed?

It probably will, seeing as the sIFR script replaces visual elements on the page after loading. The sometimes noticeable flicker on page load will disappear. Other than that, it's hard to predict whether the switch will cure the performance problem your client is talking about. You may have to try it out.

> Client has his own custom font which is not available in Google font library and he need compatibility with IE 6 to 8 also.

This sounds like a separate question to me. The best way might be serving sIFR to old browsers, and font-face to new ones.

Comment: you mean @font-face not supported by IE 6 and 7.